# install a java application

Tags: java, jar

I have small understanding problem. Why do I ever need to INSTALL (under Windows) a java desktop application (aka Intellij), if I can make a fully self-independent JAR? What are the use cases when it makes sense?

I am not expecting a full-blown answer here, I really just would like some pointers, because my Google-fu is not helping me, not sure how to formulate a correct query

EDIT I know how to run Intellij and use Java... Just asking about the point of ""installation""

Comment: Installers improve the user experience, it also provides the ability for you to customise parts of the process. If you're interacting with files on the OS, you may find it difficult to do if the App is placed in the wrong location.

Comment: i think installing just gives extra features of application registered under installed by your OS and makes it easy for user to access.

Comment: Also, sometimes installation requires privileged execution, which ordinary users may not have.  It's best to leave your own user privileged at the default level, and use a trusted installer, which will only execute the bare minimum of privileged operations.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

To run a java application from jar file, you only need to install [Java Runtime Environment](http://java.com/en). Nothing nearly as heavy as IntelliJ.  You would install an IDE such as IntelliJ to develop said jar file.

**Edit**

The jar that you develop cannot run on any platform without a JVM (Java Virtual Machine).  So if you don't install the JRE, you can't run your jar file.

Comment: Yeah I know... I mean I don't see the point of ""installation"" process

Answer (score -1):

Just like in many cases, installation is nothing but a wizard to help you to have your files in the right place.
I bet a lot of software just do that too. Many people don't wanna handle individual files to run their applications (sometimes you move or delete them without notice)